# Study of the function $g(\theta)$ for relativistic aspects

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics, graphing-functions, surface-integrals

Given this function, where $\beta=v/c$ with $v$ the magnitude of the velocity of a charge $q$, $k_e$ without the dimension is $\approx 9\cdot 10^9$,

$$g(\theta)=f(\theta)\sin \theta=\left(k_e \,q\,\frac{1-\beta^{2}}{\left[1-\beta^{2}\sin^2\theta\right]^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right)\sin \theta$$ how I can see that if I study the function $g(\theta)$ for $v$ near $c$, after is strongly peaked near $θ_0=π/2$?

Surely I should do the study of the function $g(\theta)$, but there is a quick way to verify that $g(\theta)$ is it strongly peaked near $θ_0=π/2$?

**Related question**: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/521479/gauss-theorem-in-relativistic-conditions

Comment: How do you define $\Phi(\theta)$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $\Phi(\theta)=\int_{S}\mathbf{F}(\bar{r})\,\overline{da}=\iint_{D} f(\theta) \sin \theta\, d\theta \varphi=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\varphi\int_{0}^{\theta_0}f(\theta) \sin \theta\, d\theta$.

Comment: This is not a function of $\theta$, we are integrating over that variable.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Of course. I've answered your question. The flux is a dimensional constant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $\Phi(\theta)$ is really supposed to be $\Phi(\theta_0)$. Taking a look at the integrand, we can approximate

$$(1-\beta^2\sin^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}} \approx \cos^3\theta$$

So the integral approximately evaluates to

$$\Phi(\theta_0) \approx \frac{1}{2\gamma^2 \epsilon_0}\int_0^{\theta_0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^3\theta}d\theta = \frac{\sec^2(\theta_0) - 1}{4\gamma^2 \epsilon_0} = \frac{\tan^2(\theta_0)}{4\gamma^2 \epsilon_0}$$

which goes to infinity at $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The integral can be done exactly, but this is the fastest way to see the sharp peak.

Comment: Yes it is correct $\Phi(\theta)=\Phi(\theta_0)$. I thank you very very much for your answer. But is it easy to plot $\frac{\sec^2(\theta_0) - 1}{4\gamma^2 \epsilon_0}$ considering the generic values of $\gamma$ and $\epsilon_0$? How should I plot this flux and the value of the charge is not important for the flux?

Comment: @Sebastiano $\epsilon_0$ is a fundamental constant it cannot be a generic value... but that's besides the point. If you ever want to see the behavior in one variable and plot it, don't worry about the exact value of the constants, just make up numbers that are consistent. For example in this one I would set the denominator to one. In another situation if I had to graph $\epsilon \tan x - 2\epsilon x$, I would plot $\tan x - 2x$, keeping the relative sizes the same.